# Resizing element without displacing following elements? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this web page, It's live, so take a look at it at this address:

https://mikey670.github.io/wdd130-MK/muketronics/index.html

The problem that I am having is with the element just before the body's closing tag, the div "games_grid" When one hovers over the game capsule image it expands, pushing expanding the grid downward and this pushes the footer down relative to the grids size. The grid background-color is orange so that you can see it better.
**What I want is for the footer or any other element not to move when the image expands, it should spill over the footers margin instead. I cannot set the grids height manually, because it needs to be derived from the images width, keeping aspect ratio. Only css and html**
here is the html:

```
<main>
        <div>
            <div class="title_stripe">
                <h2>Video Games</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="games_grid">
                <div class="game_box">
                    <a href="mrstretch.html">
                        <img src="images/LibraryCapsule.png" alt="Mr. Stretch cover art">
                    </a>
                    <div class="description_card">
                        <h3>Mr. Stretch and the Stolen Fortune</h3>
                        <p>Stretch from wall to treasure in this exciting puzzle-platformer collectathon!</p>
                        <p class="status">currently in development</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="game_box">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/BoulderManiacE.png" alt="Boulder Maniac cover art">
                    </a>
                    <div class="description_card">
                        <h3>Boulder Maniac</h3>
                        <p>Tumble, roll, and blast, in this chaotic and unique mining arcade!</p>
                        <p class="status"> planned developement</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="game_box"></div>
                <div class="game_box"></div>
                <div class="game_box"></div>
                <div class="game_box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

and the css:

```
#games_grid{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 25%);
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transform: rotatex(180deg);
}
        #games_grid a{
        margin:0;
    }
    .game_box{
        background-color: #df5526;
        transform: rotatex(180deg);
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: width .2s, z-index 0s .2s;
    }

    /*These are placeholders for future games*/
    .game_box:nth-of-type(3){
        background-color: #ffac15;
    }
    .game_box:nth-of-type(5){
        background-color: #ffac15;
    }

    .game_box img{
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        z-index: 3;
        opacity: 100%;
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }

    .game_box:hover{
        z-index: 4;
        width: 110%;
        transition: width 1s, z-index 0s 0s;
    }

    .game_box img:hover{
        opacity: 85%;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .game_box:hover > .description_card{
        right: -60%;
        transition: right 1s;
    }
        .description_card{
            background-color: #233532;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: auto;
            right: 10%;
            margin-top: -150%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -2;
            transition: right .5s;
        }
```

I have already tried positioning the grid absolutely, but this prevents it from deriving it's cell width from the body width, which makes the grid. Another issue with this attempted fix is that it forces me to use a wrapper that has a Hight that is undefinable, as it needs to scale with the width of the body.
I have also tried transitioning the grid cell size like this, but it did not seem to do anything.

```
#games_grid{
   grid-template-rows: 110%; /*Derived from the height that the image will grow to*/
   transition: grid-template-rows .2s;/*Same duration as the images shrinkage when it is no longer being hovered over*/
}
.game_box:hover ~ #games_grid{
    grid-template-rows: 100%;/*Forces height to match that of the images new height*/
    transition: grid-template-rows 1s;/*Matches the images hover growth speed*/
{
```

If this did successfully resize the grids row, it would theoretically offset the growth of the image by shrinking the grids size relative to the images growth. But of course, it did not change the size of the games grid.

Comment: try to resize it using `transform: scale(1.1)` instead of changing `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scale rather than width allows the user to scale the images height and width without influencing the grid size, preventing the page from growing downward.

In addition to this, adding padding to the top and bottom of the grid and changing overflow-y to visible, allows the overflow to be visible within the margin.

Comment: Can you just add your new code as example?